# TB carsh after Upgrad from 3.5.1 to 3.6

Tags: upgrade, thingsboard

Thingsboard crashes every hour after upgrading it from 3.5.1 to 3.6. Restarting the Tb service makes it reachable, but it's slow, and again after some hours it crashes.

This is the log:

```
2023-10-01 11:38:16,431 [tb-system-info-scheduler-59-thread-1] WARN  oshi.util.Util - Interrupted while sleeping for 1000 ms: sleep interrupted
2023-10-01 11:38:16,931 [sql-queue-1-ts latest-15-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - [TS Latest] Queue polling was interrupted
2023-10-01 11:38:16,931 [sql-queue-0-ts latest-14-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - [TS Latest] Queue polling was interrupted
2023-10-01 11:38:16,931 [sql-queue-0-attributes-8-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - [Attributes] Queue polling was interrupted
2023-10-01 11:38:16,931 [sql-queue-0-ts-11-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - [TS] Queue polling was interrupted
2023-10-01 11:38:16,947 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-10-01 11:38:16,947 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-10-01 11:38:17,103 [NotificationExecutorService-9-1] WARN  c.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection - HikariPool-1 - Connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@23c3fe13 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(08006), ErrorCode(0)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:383)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:316)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.executeTransactionCommand(PgConnection.java:879)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.rollback(PgConnection.java:922)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:396)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:142)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:589)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doRollbackOnCommitException(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:892)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:775)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.notification.JpaNotificationDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3e45f29.save(<generated>)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.notification.DefaultNotificationService.saveNotification(DefaultNotificationService.java:46)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.sendNotification(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:317)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.sendNotification(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:85)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.processForRecipient(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:300)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.processForTarget(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:273)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.lambda$processNotificationRequestAsync$3(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:208)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:161)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:128)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:113)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:223)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:205)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveInteger4(PGStream.java:467)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveFields(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2632)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2410)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
2023-10-01 11:38:17,103 [NotificationExecutorService-9-1] ERROR o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Commit exception overridden by rollback exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2023-10-01 11:38:17,103 [NotificationExecutorService-9-1] ERROR o.t.s.s.n.DefaultNotificationCenter - Failed to create notification for recipient 05f74060-cf86-11ec-8882-d302b9805837
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back JPA transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:593)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doRollbackOnCommitException(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:892)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:775)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.notification.JpaNotificationDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3e45f29.save(<generated>)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.notification.DefaultNotificationService.saveNotification(DefaultNotificationService.java:46)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.sendNotification(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:317)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.sendNotification(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:85)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.processForRecipient(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:300)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.processForTarget(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:273)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.lambda$processNotificationRequestAsync$3(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:208)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Unable to rollback against JDBC Connection
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:142)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:589)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:383)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:316)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.executeTransactionCommand(PgConnection.java:879)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.rollback(PgConnection.java:922)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.rollback(ProxyConnection.java:396)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.rollback(HikariProxyConnection.java)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:121)
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at java.base/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:161)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:128)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:113)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:223)
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:205)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveInteger4(PGStream.java:467)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveFields(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2632)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2410)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
2023-10-01 11:38:17,103 [NotificationExecutorService-9-1] ERROR o.t.s.s.n.DefaultNotificationCenter - Failed to create notification for recipient 4d08b0e0-4673-11ea-909d-d7d432d5ea2b
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.notification.JpaNotificationDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3e45f29.save(<generated>)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.notification.DefaultNotificationService.saveNotification(DefaultNotificationService.java:46)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.sendNotification(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:317)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.sendNotification(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:85)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.processForRecipient(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:300)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.processForTarget(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:273)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.lambda$processNotificationRequestAsync$3(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:208)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:547)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:636)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:158)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManager(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:585)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:487)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:734)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy208.createNativeEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:485)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:410)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
2023-10-01 11:38:17,119 [NotificationExecutorService-9-1] ERROR o.t.s.s.n.DefaultNotificationCenter - Failed to create notification for recipient b65cff50-9172-11ec-8882-d302b9805837
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:382)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.notification.JpaNotificationDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a3e45f29.save(<generated>)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.notification.DefaultNotificationService.saveNotification(DefaultNotificationService.java:46)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.sendNotification(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:317)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.sendNotification(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:85)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.processForRecipient(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:300)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.processForTarget(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:273)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.lambda$processNotificationRequestAsync$3(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:208)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManagerFactory is closed
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.validateNotClosed(SessionFactoryImpl.java:547)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:636)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(SessionFactoryImpl.java:158)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManager(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:585)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.invokeProxyMethod(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:487)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean$ManagedEntityManagerFactoryInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:734)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy208.createNativeEntityManager(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.createEntityManagerForTransaction(JpaTransactionManager.java:485)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:410)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
2023-10-01 11:38:17,119 [NotificationExecutorService-9-1] ERROR o.t.s.s.n.DefaultNotificationCenter - [cdd34ad0-602f-11ee-b13b-2f609736411e] Failed to update stats for notification request
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:220)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.qualifiedBeanOfType(BeanFactoryAnnotationUtils.java:95)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineQualifiedTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:515)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:496)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:342)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy277.updateStatusAndStatsById(Unknown Source)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.notification.JpaNotificationRequestDao.updateById(JpaNotificationRequestDao.java:88)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.notification.JpaNotificationRequestDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d7721836.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.aspect.SqlDaoCallsAspect.handleSqlCall(SqlDaoCallsAspect.java:162)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor74.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.sql.notification.JpaNotificationRequestDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bb54e6e.updateById(<generated>)
    at org.thingsboard.server.dao.notification.DefaultNotificationRequestService.updateNotificationRequest(DefaultNotificationRequestService.java:97)
    at org.thingsboard.server.service.notification.DefaultNotificationCenter.lambda$processNotificationRequestAsync$3(DefaultNotificationCenter.java:217)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1426)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
    at
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to the logs you provided, there was an error with the PostgreSQL database. If investigating the log further, one can find the following entry:

```
2023-10-01 11:38:17,103 [NotificationExecutorService-9-1] ERROR o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Commit exception overridden by rollback exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

So probably there was not enough memory available on the server for starting successfully. Please check the resource utilization and upgrade the RAM if necessary.